# How to consume WCF RESTfull Response format of JSON/XML in asp.net mvc 4 client

Tags: wcf, service

How to consume WCF RESTfull service in client ASP.NET MVC 3/4?. I've implemented sample RESTfull service with return type with list

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/mycities", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<string> GetData();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/mycities1/{cityId}",ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetData1(string cityId);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/XMLCity", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    List<string> GetDataXML();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/EmployeesXML", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    List<Employee> GetEmployeeXML();
}



        public List<string> GetData()
        {

            List<string> cities = new List<string>();
            cities.Add("Ahamadabad");
            cities.Add("Chennai");
            cities.Add("Bengaluru");
            cities.Add("Delhi");
            cities.Add("Kolkata");
            cities.Add("Mumbai");

            return cities;

        }

    public string GetData1(string cityId)
    {

        List<string> cities = new List<string>();
        cities.Add("Ahamadabad");
        cities.Add("Chennai");
        cities.Add("Bengaluru");
        cities.Add("Delhi");
        cities.Add("Kolkata");
        cities.Add("Mumbai");

        ShoppingCartAPIEF.ShoppingCartAdminEntities db = new ShoppingCartAPIEF.ShoppingCartAdminEntities();
        var customer = db.Customers.ToList();

        var id =  Convert.ToInt16( cityId);
        var cust = from c in customer
                   where c.Id == Convert.ToInt16(cityId)
                   select c;

        return cust.Select(l => new { l.LastName }).FirstOrDefault().LastName;
    }

    public List<string> GetDataXML()
    {

        List<string> cities = new List<string>();
        cities.Add("Ahamadabad");
        cities.Add("Chennai");
        cities.Add("Bengaluru");
        cities.Add("Delhi");
        cities.Add("Kolkata");
        cities.Add("Mumbai");

        return cities;

    }

        public List<Employee> GetEmployeeXML()
        {
            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();


            Employee emp = new Employee { EmpId = 100, FirstName = "JaiSankar", LastName = "Navarathinam" };
             Employee emp1 = new Employee { EmpId = 101, FirstName = "Vimmal", LastName = "Lodaya" };
            Employee emp2 = new Employee { EmpId = 102, FirstName = "Ganapathy", LastName = "Thayanidhi" };
            //new Employee { EmpId = 103, FirstName = "Sivakumar", LastName = "LaxmanaPerumal" };
            //new Employee { EmpId = 104, FirstName = "Gajendra", LastName = "Gowda" };

            employees.Add(emp);
            employees.Add(emp1);
            employees.Add(emp2);

            return employees;
        }
```

Client Application: Console:

Method 1 :
As we consume WCF application, add service reference in client and called as follows. This is like normal WCF application

```
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client client1 = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    var name = client1.GetData1("2");
    //Output: single name

    var cityNames = client1.GetData();
    //Output: List of strings

    var employees = client1.GetEmployeeXML();
    //OutPut: List of Employees
```

Method 2:
The above method is fine if normal WCF application, so i've tried to consume WCF RESTfull service as follows

```
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57278");

        //JSON with list of strings
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("Service1.svc/XMLService/mycities").Result;
        string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        //OutPut:  ["Ahamadabad","Chennai","Bengaluru","Delhi","Kolkata","Mumbai"]

        //XML with List of strings
        HttpResponseMessage responseXML = client.GetAsync("Service1.svc/XMLService/XMLCity").Result;
        var xml = responseXML.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        //XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        //doc.LoadXml(xml);
```

//OutPut: AhamadabadChennaiBengaluruDelhiKolkataMumbai

```
        //XML with Employee object
        HttpResponseMessage responseXML1 = client.GetAsync("Service1.svc/XMLService/EmployeesXML").Result;
        var xml1 = responseXML1.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
```

//Returning ((System.IO.MemoryStream)(xml1))
}

Here i've got list of JSON strings only or ArrayOfstring  Xml tags is coming. How to convert JSON to list of string or Employee object in client.

My Question is how to do further operation from List of strings or AraryOfString or MemoryStream.

Advance thanks
Jai.

Comment: You may want to review your question to make sure you are providing the most accurate details.  For example, your GetData service method takes no parameters.  Yet, your sample client code does.  Clean it up a bit and we should be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Rick, Thanks for your quick reply. Yes i've updated in original post itself please check and let me know

Comment: I am trying to find the same solution. It is a old post. I think you have already solved this. Can you post your solution?